# How to upgrade version of codeigniter framework?

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks, upgrade, versioning

My current project has version 1.6.3 of codeigniter framework. Now there is new release of 2.1.0 version of codeigniter. There are many new libraries and helpers included in new version. So I want to upgrade codeigniter to new version to have more functionalities and robustness.

So my questions are:

- How to upgrade version of codeigniter framework to latest version?
- Is some kind of update provided by codeigniter( like anti-virus)?
- If upgraded, will there needs to be change in my current application?

Comment: Many functions have been deprecated/renamed, so yes, there'll be changes to be made. First of all, base controller is no more "Controller" but "CI_Controller", and all classes have the CI_ prefix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the section:

- [Upgrading From a Previous Version](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/installation/upgrading.html)

Comment: Means I have to download all versions between 1.6.3 to 2.1.0. And to upgrade version with iterations. Is there any simple method than that?

Comment: @SomnathMuluk: No you don't need to download all versions. Just see what is your version of CI and what version you want to upgrade to and select that option from above link to see the guide. Documentation is pretty straight forward :)

Comment: There is no any link like `Upgrading from 1.6.3 to 2.1.0.`. Will it possible to change only system folder of latest version. And change all settings of middle iterations.

Comment: I'll turn that last comment into a question... If I want to update a 2.0.1 version into a 2.2.3 or 3.1.2, should I follow ALL the middle steps?
Another question is if it is a big risk to stay with a 2.0.1 version...?